# What is meant by linearity in more than one dimension?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, terminology

I am slightly unclear on some terminology that I have come across in the following question:

> Is $\partial _vf(0,0)$ **linear** in $v$?

My understanding of linearity for a single variable function is fine, although I'm a little unclear on what it means for a function that takes multiple variables? What is the generalisation here, and how should I interpret this word in these types of problems?

I would be grateful for any clarification here regarding the meaning of linearity in this context.

Comment: There's only one variable in your problem.

Comment: To clarify, $v = (v_1, v_2)$ @Raskolnikov

Comment: A function $f(v)$ is linear if for any vectors $v, w$ and real numbers $a,b$, $$ f(av+bw) = af(v) + bf(w).$$

Comment: @Deane Do we require differentiability at this point for linearity to be defined?

Comment: Sorry. The $f$ I wrote in my comment is *not* the same $f$ in your question. Let me try again. A function $L: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is linear if for any $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, $$ L(av+bw) = aL(v)+bL(w). $$ In your question, the function $L$ is the function $L(v) = \partial_vf(0,0)$. Here, you do have to assume that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. The easiest way to do this problem, I think, is to write $\partial_vf(0,0)$ in terms of the components of $v$ and the partial derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Why do we need differentiability? If the directional derivative is defined, why does the derivative at $(0,0)$ also need to exist? @Deane

Comment: You need differentiability to know that the directional derivative satisfies the equation $$ \partial_vf(0,0) = v^1\partial_1f(0,0) + v^2\partial_2f(0,0). $$ If you don't assume differentiability, the directional derivatives can exist but this equation does not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: how does $\partial_{v+w} $ depend on $\partial_{v} + \partial_{w} $? The question makes sense since $v$ and $w$ are vectors you can add together.

The generalization from one variable to many is to think of the many variables collected into a single vector. So you are dealing with a function of one vector variable.

Comment: What type of relationship am I looking for to determine linearity? For example, if we look at the function $\partial _v f(0,0) = \frac{v^2_1}{v_2}$ and is $0$ when $v_2 = 0$, how would we determine if this is linear in $v$?

Comment: If that is your formula for the value of the directional derivative at the origin then the function $f$ is not differentiable at the origin so you can't even ask about how $\partial_v f$ behaves there. The claim that "$\partial_v f$ is linear in $v$" makes sense only at points where $f$ is differentiable. At those points you can prove that $\partial_{v+w} j = \partial_{v} j+ \partial_{w}j$ .

Comment: Why do we require differentiability? If the directional derivative is defined at the point, then why isn't this enough?

Comment: Perhaps you can get away with a weaker assumption. You might be able to prove that if both $\partial_v f$ and $\partial_v f$  exist then so does $\partial_{v+w} f$  and that the first two add to the third. I don't think so - check to see whether the function $f$ you use as an example is a counterexample. In any case, "linearity in $v$" means what I have said in my answer. That's what you asked about.

Comment: @FD_bfa you should have that $\partial_{av}=a\partial_v$ where $a$ is a scalar and $v$ a vector. You'll also need to show $\partial_{v + w}=\partial_v+ \partial_w$ with $w$ a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}=\boldsymbol u\cdot \nabla$ be a directional derivative. Let $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ be some differentiable function and choose some point $\boldsymbol x\in\Bbb R^n$. We now define a map $$\Phi:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R \\ \Phi:\boldsymbol u\mapsto (\mathrm D_{\boldsymbol u}f)(\boldsymbol x)$$ The directional derivative is linear in the sense that the map $\Phi$ is linear.